# How to use 'most important' to compare

Tags: phrase-usage

I was going through list of words that we can use to compare two things or ideas. One of the words is ***most important***. I couldn’t find examples for this. Can someone give some examples of comparison using ***most important***?

Edit: I wanted to clarify one thing here. I am not a native English speaker. I was going through the list for words to compare/contrast two things or ideas. To my understanding compare refers to finding similarities between two things. I didn’t get how can we say two things are similar using **most important**.

We can compare using **both, similarly, as well**. For example, *They are **both** good athletes. Janet enjoys playing piano. **Similarly**, Lisa also studies piano. Lisa has three brothers. Janet has three brothers **as well**.* Does **most important** fit in this list?

Comment: Google **most important**. There are pages of relevant examples

Comment: I tried. There are many sentences with **most important** but I couldn't find some where **most important** was used to compare.

Comment: _The most important_ of a group of things is the one that is more important than all the others. Note that _most important_ (without _the_) just means _very important_.

Comment: It's ***most important*** that you learn something from the usage in this very sentence. Oftentimes, "most important" doesn't particularly imply "MORE important **than all other important things**" - it just means VERY important.

Comment: ...but [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+most+important+of%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03aNe8zkJc2g0dzKJ9_S7n2jjzfdw:1612447142709&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb3qPZsdDuAhWCWhUIHVzKAoQQpwUIJg&biw=1536&bih=732&dpr=1.25) are many written instances of the sequence ***the most important of***, almost all of which will be "literal" superlatives (specifically singling out the one thing which is more important than all other contextually comparable things).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples:

> Having a good sleep is the most important thing we need to go about our day.

> Time is the most important asset of our lives.

> Learning how to learn is most important when it comes to academics.

Essentially, the phrase 'most important' is used to compare many ideas (may be just two, although not specifically said).

Comment: I am sorry. I couldn't get it. What is **most important** comparing here, say in the second example.

Comment: @azumie - When comparing two things we say that one is _the more important_ of the two.

Comment: Ah, it's comparing other tangible assets with time. You don't have to mention what you're comparing to if it's obvious (usually). The word 'most important' usually doesn't explicitly say what it's comparing to. An example for that one would be like this: 'The cows in this farm are the most important, compared to the flock of sheep on the other side of the farm.'

Comment: @KateBunting yes, but he/she was asking the usage of the word **most** important, not _more_ important.

Comment: But you said 'may be just two'!

Comment: @KateBunting yes, I meant that as in 'it **can** be two' (possibility).

Comment: I wanted to clarify one thing here. I am not a native English speaker. I was going through the list for words to compare/contrast two things or ideas. To my understanding compare refers to similarities between two things. I didn’t get how can we say two things are similar using **most important**. From the examples it seems that we are telling that one thing is better than the other one, and not showing how one thing is similar to the second thing.

Comment: We can compare using **both, similarly, as well**. For example, *They are **both** good athletes. Janet enjoys playing piano. **Similarly**, Lisa also studies piano. Lisa has three brothers. Janet has three brothers **as well.*** How can we use **most important** for this purpose?

Comment: **Most important** picks out one thing of an entire category that singularly has the highest importance.  I don't see how you'd use this in the same sense as **as well** or **both**, since it's the *singular* thing of highest importance.

Comment: @CanadianYankee This means that **most important** cannot be used as a transition word to compare, say in a compare/contrast essay?

Comment: It could, though usually with more than two things: "When choosing jeans, style and color are important, but the **most important** factor is fit."